# Confusion between doing .copy() and using [[ ]]

Tags: pandas

I am reading "Hands-On Machine Learning with Scikit-Learn and Tensorflow" by Aurélien Géron.

Sometimes he does

```
xyz = DataFrame[["col1"]]
```

Which returns a dataframe, but other times:

```
xyz = DataFrame["col1"].copy()
```

Which reuturns a series

I do understand that both are ways of copying and not using a 'view', but when should we use each?

(ps: I only found information about views refering to arrayas in numpy... Are the arrays in numpy the same DataFrames in Pandas?)

Comment: Could you please move this question to Stackoverflow with Python, Pandas tag

Answer (score 1):

For a simple dataframe, using the .copy() function creates an independent copy of the dataframe. If you change either dataframe, this won't affect the other. For example:

```
A = df.copy(B)
```

then

if you change an item in B, A will not change

If you use an assignment

```
A = B[[...]]
```

then

if you change an item in B, A will also change

Answer (score 0):

Both are more or less the same thing.
`xyz = DataFrame[["col1"]]` is useful when you have to select one or more than one column from a dataframe. For example: `xyz = DataFrame[["col1","col2"]]`

While `xyz = DataFrame["col1"].copy()` or `df.copy()` is used for copying a complete/partial dataframe.

Note that both are exactly the same.